# Ruby sentence with dates and calibrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I have Items and Calibrations table. The items can have multiples calibrations. The table calibrations contains (date_calibration, date_expired, item_id). I must show the items with calibrations, and if it is has more than one, show only the max. Then I need write an IF sentence and show a new column with color (red, yellow and green) depending on how many days left to calibrate the item. using date_expired.

Item controller (show the max, works good)

```
@items = Item.joins(:calibrations)  
.order('items.id')  
.order('calibrations.date_expired DESC')  
.select('DISTINCT ON (items.id) items.id, items.codigo, items.numero, items.den_cont,  genre_id, state_id, affectation_id, sector_id, person_id, calibrations.date_expired AS Fecha_Vencimiento')
```

Index.html

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= item.codigo + '%03d' % item.numero.to_s %></td>
    <td><%= item.den_cont %></td>
    <td><%= item.genre.genre %></td>
    <td><%= item.state.state %></td>
    <td><%= item.affectation.affectation %></td>
    <td><%= item.sector.sector %></td>
    <td><%= item.calibrations.pluck(:date_expired).max %></td>

    <td><%= if item.calibrations(:date_expired) <= Date.today + 60 then image_tag '/semaforo/amarillo_small.png'
        elsif item.calibrations(:date_expired) <= Date.today + 30 then image_tag '/semaforo/rojo_small.png'
            else image_tag '/semaforo/verde_small.png' end %></td>
```

I have an error in the sentence if "compared with non class/module".
Can you help me with the correct sentence.? If date_expired is less than today + 60 days, must show a yellow image...then less than today + 30 days red image and the others green image..

UPDATE (work good!!)

```
<td><%= if item.calibrations.pluck(:date_expired).max <= Date.today + 30 then image_tag '/semaforo/rojo_small.png'  
elsif item.calibrations.pluck(:date_expired).max <= Date.today + 60 then image_tag '/semaforo/amarillo_small.png'
else image_tag '/semaforo/verde_small.png' end %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a many (:date_expired), note you that if you make item.calibrations you can have more than 1 calibration and you can't check more than one value with an if, you need to make another loop.

Supose that your object item have two calibrations: {calibration1, calibration2}
in this line:

```
<td><%= if item.calibrations(:date_expired) <= Date.today + 60 then image_tag '/semaforo/amarillo_small.png'
```

You're making a if for a two objects {calibration1 and calibration2} in the right side.

If doesn't work with collections.

EDITED

> item.calibrations.each do |calibration|
>
> ```
> calibration.date_expired
> ```
>
> end

Comment: Tks Pabliii..what exactly are you suggesting? Can you please point me on the right direction, I'm new on this..

Comment: Yes pabli..I understand that, what kind on sentence/expression I must use to accomplish that? Tks again!

Comment: Sorry I missundertood your question